# Adding Inventory in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm doing a project on MVC,

This is how my inventory table looks like:

[image: inventory table]

I want my `FoodId` to be grouped and the corresponding `QuantityInStyock` must be updated on the same table.

Here is how my controller looks like:

```
var add = (from m in db.Tbl_Inventory
                          where m.FoodId == pdtfid
                          select m.QuantityInStock).FirstOrDefault();

if (add == 0)
{
    In.FoodId = product.FoodId;
    In.QuantityInStock = In.QuantityInStock + product.ProductQuantity;
    db.Tbl_Inventory.Add(In);
}
else
{

}
```

I need a query in the else statement so that next time i add new product whose `FoodId` already exists in the database it should just update the `QuantityInStock` instead of creating a new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of retrieving `m.QuantityInStock`, I would suggest retrieving the `Tbl_Inventory` record and checking if the record is null. If it's null, then create a new record, otherwise update `QuantityInStock` property. See the code below

```
// get the Tbl_Inventory record where FoodId equals pdtfid
var add = (from m in db.Tbl_Inventory
              where m.FoodId == pdtfid
              select m).FirstOrDefault();

if (add == null)
{
    // insert new record
    In.FoodId = product.FoodId;
    In.QuantityInStock = In.QuantityInStock + product.ProductQuantity;
    db.Tbl_Inventory.Add(In);
}
else
{
    // update QuantityInStock from the existing record
    add.QuantityInStock += product.ProductQuantity;
}

// submit the changes
db.SaveChanges();
```